# HTTP 503 with ResourceUnhealthy

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server, outlook-restapi, microsoft-graph-mail, outlook-graph-api

Sometimes Microsoft outlook or graph API return HTTP 503 **ResourceUnhealthy** error response for specific mailboxes.
The description mentions: ResourceUnhealthy     SystemMemoryProtectionUtilizationMonitor is unhealthy

What does it means and what may cause this specific "ResourceUnhealthy" case ?

Comment: It's telling the given service reports back that the given mailbox has issues or its related services. Just make sure you can repro the issue with Graph Explorer or POSTMAN. If yes, then please open a support ticket with Microsoft through Office 365 portal and report the issue.

Comment: @Dev - I don't think it's reproducible because it's intermittent -- presumably based on changing state on the graph sever.

Comment: aah, if the issue is intermittent then its tough to trace. Still i would suggest you to check with Microsoft Support to see if there is anything specific to the given tenant or not.

Comment: When you get back the response, within the body you'll find some trace ID information. If you open up a ticket with this specific information, MS can check their logs for this specific request and find out the issue at this specific request. By the way, this specific error seems to appear every now and then.  Best way would be to handle it similar to a 429er and retry it after a few seconds.